# On hover apps leave pop up on screen

Tags: xorg, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and this happens pretty much with every app.

When I'm using an app that has some sort of hover functionality, and when that hover functionality is triggered (ie a pop up appears) then when I switch to another app using the window switch (`alt` + `tab`) that pop up will remain:

For example, here's the remains of a sublime text 3 hover hanging around on Firefox:

[image]

Can I do anything to fix this? Is it a bug? Where should I report it if it is?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes clicking inside the hovering pop-up will make it disappear. Be careful to click on the background area inside the pop-up, not on a hyperlink.

Comment: The only thing that makes the pop up disappear for me is going back to the app that created it and moving my cursor a bit not over the hover area.

Comment: If you have a graphics card you could try running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` which automatically selects and installs the proprietary graphics driver for your graphics processor if your computer has one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it says no drivers were found for automatic installation :(